# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate update objects and push other onto existing field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello I would like to update a document in my db using findByIdAndUpdate only doing minimal calls, but some values have to be pushed onto an array and other updated.

i'm sure there must be an easy way to make this into one route instead of using the two

```js
router.put('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
  Player.findByIdAndUpdate({
      _id: req.params.id
    }, {
      $push: {
        notes: req.body.notes
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    })
    .then(player => res.status(200).json(player))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({
      'err': 'updating went wrong'
    }))
})
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
  let updates = {};
  if (req.body.first) {
    updates.first = req.body.first;
  }
  if (req.body.last) {
    updates.last = req.body.last;
  }
  if (req.body.school) {
    updates.school = req.body.school;
  }
  if (req.body.rank) {
    updates.rank = req.body.rank;
  }
  Player.findByIdAndUpdate({
      _id: req.params.id
    }, updates, {
      new: true
    })
    .then(player => res.status(200).json(player))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({
      'err': 'updating went wrong'
    }))
})
```

Comment: You can simply do this within a single query `{ $push: { }, $set: { }}`